# I have an rabbit amqp listener in springboot, It stucks without closing the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpool, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have the following code snippet in my actual code. I have mutiple consumers listening to a queue.

```
 @RabbitListener
 private void abc(ETLConfigDTO config){
  try{
   log.info("load started");
   loadService.loadData(config);
  }
  catch(Exception e){
   log.error("Load failed"):
  }
  finally{
   log.info("finished processing"):
  }
 }
```

loadData() takes few minutes to few hours of processing. Its kind of etl processing. There is intensove logging inside this method, so i know in which state the process is.
The problem is that the process is kind of stuck inside loadPlans() method. The message in the queue is in unacknowledged state since it is still processing which i need in that way.
There is no exception since catch is not printing anything or even the finally block.
I also have a spring cron (5 minutes interval) in the same class which is also running fine and doing its tasks.

The point to note is that this is running fine if I not use rabbit amqp.

Is there any connection/network drop? Or any timeout? Or the main thread is hung/dead? I am really not understanding what is happening here.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:
Thanks Gary**,
I see this in `jstack 19`:

```
"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #25 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5615b3d800 nid=0x2f runnable [0x00007f56703cd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        - locked <0x000000067a6bada8> (a java.lang.Object)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:940)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        - locked <0x000000067a6baea0> (a sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
        - locked <0x000000067a717cb8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
        - locked <0x000000067a6b4b60> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
        - locked <0x000000067a6b4b60> (a sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpResponse.getRawStatusCode(SimpleClientHttpResponse.java:48)
        at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpResponse.getStatusCode(AbstractClientHttpResponse.java:33)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.getHttpStatusCode(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.hasError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:602)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
..
...
...
...


Please advise.
```

**NEW UPDATE:**
I have increase memory -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024M  -Xms4096M -Xmx4096M

The thread is being stuck on oracle connection now.

```
"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1" #25 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007ff6102c8800 nid=0x33 runnable [0x00007ff619ad9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:300)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:106)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:315)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:260)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:185)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:102)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:124)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:80)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:290)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeBatch(OracleStatement.java:4536)
        - locked <0x00000007b01c6b20> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:572)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1BatchUpdateStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:559)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:405)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:611)
...
...
```

Comment: Can you post properties file?

Comment: I have configured rabbit via beans

Answer (score 1):

Your listener is rather unusual; in most cases it would be `void listen(SomeObject)` where the listener processes the object and exits and the message is acknowledged.

You appear to be ignoring the contents of the message and simply using its presence to trigger `loadData()`.

Regardless, by default, the message won't be acknowledged until the method exits; the container thread will remain in the listener method until it exits.

The default acknowledge mode for the container is AUTO which means the container will automatically acknowledge (or reject) the message when the method exits.

You can change the acknowledge mode to NONE which means RabbitMQ does not require an acknowledgment at all and will remove the message immediately.

However, the container thread will still run in the method until the method exits.

The message will be lost if the application crashes.

Comment: Sorry about that updated the listener, it is reading the message and processing it in loadData()

Comment: So what is the question? As I said it's normal to leave the message unacknowledged until the load completes and the listener exits, unless you change the acknowledge mode to NONE.

Comment: The question is that the main thread stucks in loadData() which it should not... It stays there forever..

Comment: But that's your code and has nothing to do with the framework so there's nothing we can do about it - take a thread dump to see what it's doing.

Comment: How can i do that? Is there a way to log the Thread Activity?

Comment: There are several ways. e.g. the JDK comes with a tool `jstack` just find the pid of the jvm (e.g. with `jps`).

Comment: Thanks Gary, I updated above, the stack trace by the jstack command. There seems to be a lock. Please advise what should be done to avoid this?

Comment: `at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)` - it looks like you are blocked waiting for some data from an HTTP server; this is completely unrelated to spring-amqp; I suggest you debug that independently.

Comment: Yeah, i am hitting some endpoints, parsing data and loading it to database within that method.

Comment: Hi Gary,
Update new stack trace.
is this related to db locks?

Comment: I am here to support the frameworks I work on; I do not have time to help you debug your application code. `at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)` - this time it's waiting for the database result - perhaps you can add some debug logging to your application to show progress (read from FTP, write to database etc).